# Can anyone identify this fruiting tree/shrub for me?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, flowers

First saw it in tree form, in Madeira, where it was (I'm told) mis-identified as mango. I've now found it in Southern California, grown as a hedge.

[image]

Comment: We need to see some foliage (leaves, stems) as well please, important for correct ID- I can say, though,  its not a bottlebrush (Callistemon)

Answer (score 4):

They look like pineapple guava flowers to me, Iv got a couple of plants. If it's been misidentified as a mango that makes sense too as the fruits look like small unripe mangos.